# Unable to query Accounts with Related activities

Tags: soql, execute-anonymous

I am unable to query accounts with related task Criteria

```
List<Account> acc= new List<Account>();
acc=[Select id,name from account where Id IN (Select id,WhatId,CreatedBy.Name,ActivityDate,CreatedDate FROM Tasks)];
```

I'm getting error unexpected token "," Please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Basically, Entity 'Task' is not supported for semi join inner selects.

So, first you need to query for `AccountId` and then in 2nd query fetch the Account records.

```
Set<id> acct = [Select AccountId FROM Task];
List<Account> acc = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Id In:acct ];
```

Comment: But we can't use the task object in inner join

Comment: find my updated answer

Comment: It's important to note that there is a difference between querying on `Task.AccountId` and `Task.WhatId`. The result set for the former is a lot wider.

Comment: But is there any possibility to export results with nested queries. Right now I am executing in anonymous

Answer (score -1):

```
  Please Try This Query your problem resolve
    List<Account> acc= new List<Account>();

    acc=[Select id,name,(Select id,WhatId,CreatedBy.Name,ActivityDate,CreatedDate FROM Tasks) from Account];

    System.debug('-->'+acc);

    if this query is helpful for you then please mark the `
```